# How to get value of css property defined in custom-style element (Polymer Dart 1.0)?

Tags: polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I have defined the [css property at document level](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#custom-style):

```
<style is="custom-style">
    :root {
        --my-color: black;
    }
</style>
```

How can I get the value of `--my-color` from the dart code inside a polymer element? I have tried to use `customStyle['--my-color']` but it returns `null`.

Comment: You might need to select the style element in head and then call `customStyle['--my-color'] on it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems not to be possible on page-level `style is="custom-style"`, only for CSS variables declared int style tags within Polymer elements.
See also `customStyle` in http://polymer.github.io/polymer/

> An element's style properties can be directly modified by setting key-value pairs in customStyle on the element (analogous to setting style) and then calling updateStyles().

"An element's style properties ..."

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, like this:

```
Polymer({
    is: 'my-el',

    attached: function() {        
        console.log(this.getComputedStyleValue('--my-color'));
    }
});
```

Note i used `attached` callback instead of `ready`